# Filtering By Google Analytics Custom Dimension in BigQuery

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I've been trying to add a custom dimension filter to a working query I have in BigQuery. Custom dimensions and their nesting definitely add some complexity to queries but I've been able to figure it out in the past. This time though I'm not having any luck.

The query is long but essentially a checkout funnel that we are tracking. I've added the custom dimension to the SELECTs that I thought were required but I'm getting the error "Unrecognized name: PracticeName at [274:9]".

```html
#standardSQL
WITH
  ga_tables AS (
  SELECT
    CAST(CONCAT(SUBSTR(date,1,4),'-',SUBSTR(date,5,2),'-',SUBSTR(date,7,2)) AS DATE) AS Date,
    COUNT(DISTINCT s3_fullVisitorId) AS users,
    COUNT(s0_firstHit) AS product_views,
    COUNT(s1_firstHit) AS carts,
    COUNT(s2_firstHit) AS order_confirmation
  FROM (
    SELECT
      IFNULL(s3.date,
        IFNULL(s0.date,
          IFNULL(s1.date,
            s2.date))) AS date,
      s3.fullVisitorId s3_fullVisitorId,
      s0.fullVisitorId s0_fullVisitorId,
      s0.visitId,
      s0.firstHit s0_firstHit,
      s1.firstHit s1_firstHit,
      s2.firstHit s2_firstHit
    FROM (
        # user subquery
      SELECT
        date,
        fullVisitorId,
        visitId,
        (
        SELECT
          MAX(IF(index = 27,
              value,
              ''))
        FROM
          UNNEST(customDimensions)) AS PracticeName
      FROM
        `big-query-project-34643.162968675.ga_sessions_*` ga
      WHERE
        _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 100 DAY))
        AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 0 DAY))
        AND totals.visits = 1
      GROUP BY
        date,
        PracticeName,
        fullVisitorId,
        visitId) s3
    FULL OUTER JOIN ((
          # first subquery
        SELECT
          date,
          fullVisitorId,
          visitId,
          MIN(h.hitNumber) AS firstHit,
          (
          SELECT
            MAX(IF(index = 27,
                value,
                ''))
          FROM
            UNNEST(ga.customDimensions)) AS PracticeName
        FROM
          `big-query-project-34643.162968675.ga_sessions_*` ga,
          UNNEST(hits) AS h
        WHERE
          _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 100 DAY))
          AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 0 DAY))
          AND REGEXP_CONTAINS(h.page.pagePath, '/p/')
          AND totals.visits = 1
        GROUP BY
          date,
          PracticeName,
          fullVisitorId,
          visitId)) s0
    ON
      s3.fullVisitorId = s0.fullVisitorId
      AND s3.visitId = s0.visitId
    FULL OUTER JOIN ((
          # Second Subquery
        SELECT
          date,
          fullVisitorId,
          visitId,
          MIN(h.hitNumber) AS firstHit,
          (
          SELECT
            MAX(IF(index = 27,
                value,
                ''))
          FROM
            UNNEST(ga.customDimensions)) AS PracticeName
        FROM
          `big-query-project-34643.162968675.ga_sessions_*` ga,
          UNNEST(hits) AS h
        WHERE
          _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 100 DAY))
          AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 0 DAY))
          AND REGEXP_CONTAINS(h.page.pagePath, '/cart')
          AND totals.visits = 1
        GROUP BY
          date,
          PracticeName,
          fullVisitorId,
          visitId)) s1
    ON
      s0.fullVisitorId = s1.fullVisitorId
      AND s0.visitId = s1.visitId
    FULL OUTER JOIN ((
          # Third Subquery
        SELECT
          date,
          fullVisitorId,
          visitId,
          MIN(h.hitNumber) AS firstHit,
          (
          SELECT
            MAX(IF(index = 27,
                value,
                ''))
          FROM
            UNNEST(ga.customDimensions)) AS PracticeName
        FROM
          `big-query-project-34643.162968675.ga_sessions_*` ga,
          UNNEST(hits) AS h
        WHERE
          _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 100 DAY))
          AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 0 DAY))
          AND REGEXP_CONTAINS(h.page.pagePath, '/orderconfirmation')
          AND totals.visits = 1
        GROUP BY
          date,
          PracticeName,
          fullVisitorId,
          visitId)) s2
    ON
      s1.fullVisitorId = s2.fullVisitorId
      AND s1.visitId = s2.visitId)
  GROUP BY
    date
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    CAST(CONCAT(SUBSTR(date,1,4),'-',SUBSTR(date,5,2),'-',SUBSTR(date,7,2)) AS DATE) AS Date,
    COUNT(DISTINCT s3_fullVisitorId) AS users,
    COUNT(s0_firstHit) AS product_views,
    COUNT(s1_firstHit) AS order_details,
    COUNT(s2_firstHit) AS order_confirmation
  FROM (
    SELECT
      IFNULL(s3.date,
        IFNULL(s0.date,
          IFNULL(s1.date,
            s2.date))) AS date,
      s3.fullVisitorId s3_fullVisitorId,
      s0.fullVisitorId s0_fullVisitorId,
      s0.visitId,
      s0.firstHit s0_firstHit,
      s1.firstHit s1_firstHit,
      s2.firstHit s2_firstHit
    FROM (
        # user subquery
      SELECT
        date,
        fullVisitorId,
        visitId,
        (
        SELECT
          MAX(IF(index = 27,
              value,
              ''))
        FROM
          UNNEST(gart.customDimensions)) AS PracticeName
      FROM
        `big-query-project-34643.162968675.ga_exportKey_view_2` gart
      WHERE
        totals.visits = 1
      GROUP BY
        date,
        PracticeName,
        fullVisitorId,
        visitId) s3
    FULL OUTER JOIN ((
          # first subquery
        SELECT
          date,
          fullVisitorId,
          visitId,
          MIN(h.hitNumber) AS firstHit,
          (
          SELECT
            MAX(IF(index = 27,
                value,
                ''))
          FROM
            UNNEST(gart.customDimensions)) AS PracticeName
        FROM
          `big-query-project-34643.162968675.ga_exportKey_view_2` gart,
          UNNEST(hits) AS h
        WHERE
          REGEXP_CONTAINS(h.page.pagePath, '/p/')
          AND totals.visits = 1
        GROUP BY
          date,
          PracticeName,
          fullVisitorId,
          visitId)) s0
    ON
      s3.fullVisitorId = s0.fullVisitorId
      AND s3.visitId = s0.visitId
    FULL OUTER JOIN ((
          # Second Subquery
        SELECT
          date,
          fullVisitorId,
          visitId,
          MIN(h.hitNumber) AS firstHit,
          (
          SELECT
            MAX(IF(index = 27,
                value,
                ''))
          FROM
            UNNEST(gart.customDimensions)) AS PracticeName
        FROM
          `big-query-project-34643.162968675.ga_exportKey_view_2` gart,
          UNNEST(hits) AS h
        WHERE
          REGEXP_CONTAINS(h.page.pagePath, '/cart')
          AND totals.visits = 1
        GROUP BY
          date,
          PracticeName,
          fullVisitorId,
          visitId)) s1
    ON
      s0.fullVisitorId = s1.fullVisitorId
      AND s0.visitId = s1.visitId
    FULL OUTER JOIN ((
          # Third Subquery
        SELECT
          date,
          fullVisitorId,
          visitId,
          MIN(h.hitNumber) AS firstHit,
          (
          SELECT
            MAX(IF(index = 27,
                value,
                ''))
          FROM
            UNNEST(gart.customDimensions)) AS PracticeName
        FROM
          `big-query-project-34643.162968675.ga_exportKey_view_2` gart,
          UNNEST(hits) AS h
        WHERE
          REGEXP_CONTAINS(h.page.pagePath, '/orderconfirmation')
          AND totals.visits = 1
        GROUP BY
          date,
          PracticeName,
          fullVisitorId,
          visitId)) s2
    ON
      s1.fullVisitorId = s2.fullVisitorId
      AND s1.visitId = s2.visitId)
  GROUP BY
    date)
SELECT
  Date AS Date,
  SUM(users) AS users,
  SUM(product_views) AS product_views,
  SUM(carts) AS Carts,
  SUM(order_confirmation) AS order_confirmation
FROM
  ga_tables
WHERE
  LOWER(PracticeName) NOT LIKE '%demo%'
  AND PracticeName NOT LIKE 'asdf'
GROUP BY
  Date
ORDER BY
  Date DESC
```

Any help figuring this out would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use practicename in the where clause but it's not avaible in final version of ga_tables. Look at top of your code. It looks like you had working funnel, then you decided to add custom dimension there, but you didn't add it to all places it should be.

```
WITH
  ga_tables AS (
  SELECT
    CAST(CONCAT(SUBSTR(date,1,4),'-',SUBSTR(date,5,2),'-',SUBSTR(date,7,2)) AS date) AS date,
    PracticeName,
    COUNT(DISTINCT s3_fullvisitorid) AS users,
    COUNT(s0_firsthit) AS product_views,
    COUNT(s1_firsthit) AS carts,
    COUNT(s2_firsthit) AS order_confirmation
  FROM (
    SELECT
      ifnull(s3.date,
        ifnull(s0.date,
          ifnull(s1.date,
            s2.date))) AS date,
      s0.practicename PracticeName,
      s3.fullvisitorid s3_fullvisitorid,
      s0.fullvisitorid s0_fullvisitorid,
      s0.visitid,
      s0.firsthit s0_firsthit,
      s1.firsthit s1_firsthit,
      s2.firsthit s2_firsthit
    FROM (
      SELECT
        date,
        fullvisitorid,
        visitid,
        (
        SELECT
          MAX(IF(index = 27,
              value,
              ''))
        FROM
          UNNEST(customdimensions)) AS practicename
      FROM
        `virtual-core-194015.157925963.ga_sessions_*` ga
      WHERE
        _table_suffix BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 100 day))
        AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 0 day))
        AND totals.visits = 1
      GROUP BY
        date,
        practicename,
        fullvisitorid,
        visitid) s3
    FULL OUTER JOIN ((
        SELECT
          date,
          fullvisitorid,
          visitid,
          MIN(h.hitnumber) AS firsthit,
          (
          SELECT
            MAX(IF(index = 27,
                value,
                ''))
          FROM
            UNNEST(ga.customdimensions)) AS practicename
        FROM
          `virtual-core-194015.157925963.ga_sessions_*` ga,
          UNNEST(hits) AS h
        WHERE
          _table_suffix BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 100 day))
          AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 0 day))
          AND REGEXP_CONTAINS(h.page.pagepath, '/p/')
          AND totals.visits = 1
        GROUP BY
          date,
          practicename,
          fullvisitorid,
          visitid)) s0
    ON
      s3.fullvisitorid = s0.fullvisitorid
      AND s3.visitid = s0.visitid
    FULL OUTER JOIN ((
        SELECT
          date,
          fullvisitorid,
          visitid,
          MIN(h.hitnumber) AS firsthit,
          (
          SELECT
            MAX(IF(index = 27,
                value,
                ''))
          FROM
            UNNEST(ga.customdimensions)) AS practicename
        FROM
          `virtual-core-194015.157925963.ga_sessions_*` ga,
          UNNEST(hits) AS h
        WHERE
          _table_suffix BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 100 day))
          AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 0 day))
          AND REGEXP_CONTAINS(h.page.pagepath, '/cart')
          AND totals.visits = 1
        GROUP BY
          date,
          practicename,
          fullvisitorid,
          visitid)) s1
    ON
      s0.fullvisitorid = s1.fullvisitorid
      AND s0.visitid = s1.visitid
    FULL OUTER JOIN (( # third subquery
        SELECT
          date,
          fullvisitorid,
          visitid,
          MIN(h.hitnumber) AS firsthit,
          (
          SELECT
            MAX(IF(index = 27,
                value,
                ''))
          FROM
            UNNEST(ga.customdimensions)) AS practicename
        FROM
          `virtual-core-194015.157925963.ga_sessions_*` ga,
          UNNEST(hits) AS h
        WHERE
          _table_suffix BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 100 day))
          AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 0 day))
          AND REGEXP_CONTAINS(h.page.pagepath, '/orderconfirmation')
          AND totals.visits = 1
        GROUP BY
          date,
          practicename,
          fullvisitorid,
          visitid)) s2
    ON
      s1.fullvisitorid = s2.fullvisitorid
      AND s1.visitid = s2.visitid)
  GROUP BY
    date,2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    CAST(CONCAT(SUBSTR(date,1,4),'-',SUBSTR(date,5,2),'-',SUBSTR(date,7,2)) AS date) AS date,
    practicename,
    COUNT(DISTINCT s3_fullvisitorid) AS users,
    COUNT(s0_firsthit) AS product_views,
    COUNT(s1_firsthit) AS order_details,
    COUNT(s2_firsthit) AS order_confirmation
  FROM (
    SELECT
      ifnull(s3.date,
        ifnull(s0.date,
          ifnull(s1.date,
            s2.date))) AS date,
      s0.practicename practicename,
      s3.fullvisitorid s3_fullvisitorid,
      s0.fullvisitorid s0_fullvisitorid,
      s0.visitid,
      s0.firsthit s0_firsthit,
      s1.firsthit s1_firsthit,
      s2.firsthit s2_firsthit
    FROM ( # USER subquery
      SELECT
        date,
        fullvisitorid,
        visitid,

        (
        SELECT
          MAX(IF(index = 27,
              value,
              ''))
        FROM
          UNNEST(gart.customdimensions)) AS practicename
      FROM
        `virtual-core-194015.157925963.ga_sessions_*` gart
      WHERE
        totals.visits = 1
      GROUP BY
        date,
        practicename,
        fullvisitorid,
        visitid) s3

    FULL OUTER JOIN (( # first subquery
        SELECT
          date,
          fullvisitorid,
          visitid,
          MIN(h.hitnumber) AS firsthit,
          (
          SELECT
            MAX(IF(index = 27,
                value,
                ''))
          FROM
            UNNEST(gart.customdimensions)) AS practicename
        FROM
          `virtual-core-194015.157925963.ga_sessions_*` gart,
          UNNEST(hits) AS h
        WHERE
          REGEXP_CONTAINS(h.page.pagepath, '/p/')
          AND totals.visits = 1
        GROUP BY
          date,
          practicename,
          fullvisitorid,
          visitid)) s0
    ON
      s3.fullvisitorid = s0.fullvisitorid
      AND s3.visitid = s0.visitid
    FULL OUTER JOIN (( # second subquery
        SELECT
          date,
          fullvisitorid,
          visitid,
          MIN(h.hitnumber) AS firsthit,
          (
          SELECT
            MAX(IF(index = 27,
                value,
                ''))
          FROM
            UNNEST(gart.customdimensions)) AS practicename
        FROM
          `virtual-core-194015.157925963.ga_sessions_*` gart,
          UNNEST(hits) AS h
        WHERE
          REGEXP_CONTAINS(h.page.pagepath, '/cart')
          AND totals.visits = 1
        GROUP BY
          date,
          practicename,
          fullvisitorid,
          visitid)) s1
    ON
      s0.fullvisitorid = s1.fullvisitorid
      AND s0.visitid = s1.visitid
    FULL OUTER JOIN (( # third subquery
        SELECT
          date,
          fullvisitorid,
          visitid,
          MIN(h.hitnumber) AS firsthit,
          (
          SELECT
            MAX(IF(index = 27,
                value,
                ''))
          FROM
            UNNEST(gart.customdimensions)) AS practicename
        FROM
          `virtual-core-194015.157925963.ga_sessions_*` gart,
          UNNEST(hits) AS h
        WHERE
          REGEXP_CONTAINS(h.page.pagepath, '/orderconfirmation')
          AND totals.visits = 1
        GROUP BY
          date,
          practicename,
          fullvisitorid,
          visitid)) s2
    ON
      s1.fullvisitorid = s2.fullvisitorid
      AND s1.visitid = s2.visitid)
  GROUP BY
    date,practicename)
SELECT
  date AS date,
  SUM(users) AS users,
  SUM(product_views) AS product_views,
  SUM(carts) AS carts,
  SUM(order_confirmation) AS order_confirmation
FROM
  ga_tables
WHERE
  LOWER(PracticeName) NOT LIKE '%demo%'
  AND PracticeName NOT LIKE 'asdf'
GROUP BY
  date
ORDER BY
  date DESC
```